# Dynamic URL with curl C++

Tags: c++, qt, curl

Here is my C++ code for curl GET query (in QT5)

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/?site=http://google.fr&name=test");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.42.0");
```

This code works perfectly! the request is launched.

I would like to change the path of the field of the application.
I get the domain by this variable

```
QString domain = ui->editDomain->text();
```

I tried:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, domain + "?site=http://google.fr&name=test");
```

But here the query is not launching! And I do not understand why...
And no error at compilation

Comment: What is the content of domain?

Comment: @user3606329 A php file that retrieves the GET variable and writes it to a file. But it works very well with the url hard coded!

Comment: Make sure that you have not missed a `/` when you put the url together. `domain.com?site=..` is not valid. That's why I asked for the content.

Comment: FYI there's already network functionality built into Qt, no need to use Curl unless there's some esoteric functionality you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` functions take a c-string.  `domain + "?site=http://google.fr&name=test"` gives you a `QString` which the function doesn't know how to handle.  What you need to do is convert the resulting `QString` into a c-string.  You can do that like

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (domain + "?site=http://google.fr&name=test").toUtf8().constData());
```

Comment: Oooh!! Very interesting to know and it works perfectly well =) Thank you

Comment: The third parameter is not always a c-string! The type that needs to be passed as the third parameter to `curl_easy_setopt` depends on the option passed as the second parameter. Read the [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) for details.